# DataGridView control not properly rendering

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, controls

I am working on a DataGridView in VS 2012 using .NET 4.0

This DataGridView's data is populated by a direct SQL query and can have a lot of columns. The problem is that when there are a large number of columns, scrolling all the way to the right and then scrolling back left causes some column titles appear to be cutoff. The title is redrawn as soon as it is moused over.

Before mouse over:
[image: Before mouse over]
After mouse over:
[image: After mouse over]

Does anyone know what is going on here/how to fix it so users don't see truncated column titles?

I have tried doublebuffering and messing with WS_EX_COMPOSITED (and both) and the problem still occurs.

Comment: looks like this question has been asked recently before. Your problem is really **strange**. Unless you have some kind of **customization** on your `DataGridView`.

Comment: That's because I asked it previously, but has some errors in the question. And I am using the standard Window System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

Answer (score 0):

> When working with very large amounts of data, you can set the VirtualMode property to true to display a subset of the available data. Virtual mode requires the implementation of a data cache from which the DataGridView control is populated. For more information, see Data Display Modes in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control.

.. as suggested by the MSDN library [DataGridView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't want to show less data, I am just wondering if this is bug in the control/if there is some method to call or step to take to fix this.